CAN BUS Chassis Grounding
Hoping to get get some guidance on correct grounding for a CAN Bus I have designed. The following diagram gives a high level overview of the system connectivity:

Some notes on the setup:

There are a total of 12 nodes, I've only drawn 4 in the interest of repetition.
Each node is a custom designed PCB.
Each node has an onboard DC-DC SMPS which powers the MCU, CAN transceiver and applicable on-board peripherals. These all share the same common ground (labelled 0V) in the diagram.
CAN_H and CAN_L are twisted pair.
CAN reference (CAN_GND) is the 0V system ground.
Each node has mounting holes tied to 0V net, which directly tie the PCB to the chassis, indicated by the chassis ground on each node.
Single Board Computer has its ground reference tied to the chassis.
Pump 1 and Pump 2 are simply turned on/off via a MOSFET.

I believe this may be creating a ground loop as I am connecting 0V between each node via the power cable as well as connecting each nodes 0V net to the chassis.
I am seeing quite a clean CAN signal when running on the bench (with no chassis connection). Inside the chassis, there's a significant amount of extra noise visible on the signals.
I'm looking for guidance on best practice on how I should be running both the CAN reference as well as how the nodes should be tied to the chassis. I.e. should all the nodes and devices powered by those nodes all be connected to the chassis?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT 1: Included more details about the setup and added some further details about loads drawing current within the system.

If there’s no current flowing via earth, then there’s no ground loop. The dc/dc converters may be injecting high frequency currents. Are your dc/dc converters isolated types? If so, you may need to add a capacitor across the input and output 0V pins. Something like 100nF.

DC/DC converter is non-isolated module - Model number: MPM3620AGQV-Z

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

One issue is that if there are currents flowing in each/some nodes, then:
Either those currents return through the chassis - which is normally unacceptable and in your case particularly unacceptable, since you also have safety ground there.
Or otherwise they go through the system ground, in which case they add ground noise for the CAN bus. This would be the reason why CAN is a 3 signal bus: CANH, CANL and CAN_GND. You are missing the CAN_GND signal and that can cause problems with noise and error frames, as the supply becomes the ground reference instead. All ground noise in the entire system passes through there.
The ground layouts per node and the place where you connect it to chassis and where you connect the various grounds together will however be important no matter if you use a CAN ground or not.

Yep so my CAN_GND is simply the supplies GND (0V). Is this inherently bad? My understanding is that the alternative is isolating each individual node, which may be needed in some instances, but not all.

Given your first two statements about the currents possible return paths, would you be able to recommend how I should modify the node-to node GND and node-chassis connections? If you need any further info from me let me know.

@gid204 You haven't mentioned what kind of system this is or if there are any significant currents anywhere.

I've added lots more detail and clarified what I'm actually after in the original post. Cheers

@gid204 Ok that looks like you have some serious ground currents and perhaps fluctuations in potential whenever something gets activated. If you just disconnect the things that draw current and observe that the CAN bus works better, then you have found the problem. CAN aside & in general, this system will need a star ground design because of the big currents - you can't do a multi-drop design. Alternatively use raw machine voltage to supply the things that draw current and ground them separately.
